Issue with installing the barcode-scanning
I'm working on Ionic Vue project. I want to install the Barcode-Scanner, but I'm running into the issue:
Error during scanning: Error: The Google Barcode Scanner Module is not available. You must install it first.
I have installed @capactior/barcode-scaning@6.0.0, @capacitor/core@6.0.0. I gave all the important permission in the AndroidManifest.xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" 
 <meta-data android:name="com.google.mlkit.vision.DEPENDENCIES" android:value="barcode_ui" />/>


This is how my code look like:
const showToast = async (message: string) => {
  const toast = await toastController.create({
    message: message,
    duration: 2000,
    position: 'bottom',
  })
  await toast.present();
}

const openCamera = async () => {
  const cameraPermission = await Camera.requestPermissions();

  if (cameraPermission.camera !== 'granted') {
    console.error('Camera permission is not granted');
    return;
  }

  try {
    const result = await BarcodeScanner.scan();
    const firstResult = result.barcodes.pop();
    console.log(firstResult);
    if (firstResult) {
      console.log("Barcode found");
    } else {
      await showToast('No barcode found');
    }
  } catch (error) {
    await showToast('No barcode found!');
  }
};

const installBarcode = async () => {
  try {
    const isModuleInstalled = await BarcodeScanner.isGoogleBarcodeScannerModuleAvailable();
    if (isModuleInstalled) {
      installStatus.value = "Module is already installed!";
      return;
    }

    await BarcodeScanner.installGoogleBarcodeScannerModule();
    installStatus.value = "Installation successful!";
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error installing scanner module', error);
    installStatus.value = "Installation error!";
  }
};

Unfortunately that error I've said earlier appears and No barcode found.
I want to create a working barcode-scanner. I've tried installing it, adding permissions to it. Changing emulator. Nothing seems to work.

try this plugin: https://capawesome.io/plugins/mlkit/barcode-scanning/
